# overlaying and blending comes out looking pink

Tags: ffmpeg

I have four assets, a white background, a red background, a circle on black, and a pikachu painting.

Here are the assets (all rgb pngs, no alpha channels):-
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm trying to overlay the red onto white to give red_on_white, then overlay the circle onto the red_on_white, to give circle_on_red_on_white.  I then want to crop part of that now 'rasterised' output out from circle_on_red_on_white, and blend the crop of that with the pikachu asset.  And then overlay the blended pair back onto the circle_on_red_on_white.

However, the blended pair comes out looking pink, which is not right.

The blended pair should come out looking like this:-
[image]
which is how it comes out with this line of code:-

```
ffmpeg -i circle_rgb_50.png -i pikachu_rgb.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]blend=all_mode=screen" pikachu_screened_over_circle.png
```

However, when I do the overlays and crop aswell, like this:-

```
ffmpeg -i bg_rgb_png.png -i color_clip_rgb24_png.png -i circle_rgb_50.png -i pikachu_rgb.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out1];[out1][2:v]overlay=0:0[out2];[out2]split[out2_1][out2_2];[out2_1]crop=50:50:0:0:exact=1,setsar=1[cropped2];[3:v][cropped2]blend=all_mode=screen[blended];[out2_2][blended]overlay=0:0" white_red_circle_pika_from_pngs.png
```

it comes out looking pink like this:-
[image]

I was wondering why it is that it comes out looking pink ? and how I can make it look like it does when it was just the circle and pikachu being blended together ?

So that you can take a crop of the 'rasterised' underlayer, and use that crop for the blend, and then overlay the blend back onto the 'rasterised' underlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering why it is that it comes out looking pink ?

Because when you apply `overlay` filter you get alpha channel. You may check it in the output of ffmpeg (in Output section):

```
... Video: png, rgba...
```

or with any tool that shows channels.

> and how I can make it look like it does when it was just the circle and pikachu being blended together ?

You may force `overlay` filter to use `rgb` format and make your `filter_complex` simpler:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -i color_clip_rgb24_png.png \
  -i circle_rgb_50.png \
  -i pikachu_rgb.png \
  -filter_complex \
    "[1:v][2:v]blend=all_mode=screen[pica_circle]; 
     [0:v][pica_circle]overlay=format=rgb" \
  white_red_circle_pika_from_pngs.png
```

Comment: That's great, thank you.  What if all the inputs were rgba and you wanted an rgba output ?

Comment: @OneWorld Looks like you've chosen the wrong image creation tool.